# How to limit DatePicker to display only current year in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm using KeyboardDatePicker in my React App to allow users select travel date but I want to limit the date selection to the current year only, meaning user shouldn't be able to select any next year date starting from January 1st 2022. My code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";

import { KeyboardDatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const [date, setDate] = useState();

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          style={{ width: 200, height: 28 }}
          minDate={new Date()}
          disableToolbar={true}
          margin="none"
          variant="inline"
          value={date}
          inputVariant="outlined"
          emptyLabel="Select Date"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            onFocus: (e) => {
              setIsOpen(true);
            }
          }}
          PopoverProps={{
            disableRestoreFocus: true,
            onClose: () => {
              setIsOpen(false);
            }
          }}
          InputProps={{
            onFocus: () => {
              setIsOpen(true);
            }
          }}
          open={isOpen}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-kepler-iqfkh?file=/src/App.js:23-1391)

when I add `maxDate={new Date().getFullYear}` date picker limits selection to the current month(June). How can I limit date selection so user can't select any date of the next year?. For exp. in 2021 user should be able to select the future dates only from 2021, in 2022 only dates from 2022 and etc.  Any help and advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.getFullYear` returns a string, but `maxDate` expects a `ParsableDate`. Pass the correct value (which is a date - 31 Dec of Current year) to `maxDate` and see if this works.

Comment: @Brian, tried it, date picker still limits selection to the current month(June)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a invalid type for the maxDate. maxDate expects a value of type Date.

To limit the value to only current year,

`` const lastDateOfYear = `12/31/${new Date().getFullYear()}`; ``

Assign this to maxDate,`maxDate={new Date(lastDateOfYear)}`

Comment: the format of the date was incorrect, corrected it. Should work now